# How to pass bash shell variable to python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I read a lot of examples with same problem but I didn't solve it. I have a small python app that runs some bash commands. Most of lines are bash shell commands. App has some bash shell variables that I need them to pass outside from bash shell to python part file. I want `start` and `end` variables to pass outside of part bash shell. I have to say that I write `python3 count.py enp35s0` to run my python app.

How can I do that?

I am sorry for my English, I am not native speaker.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    n = sys.argv[1]

def capture():
    subprocess.run(['/bin/bash', '-c', bash, n], check=True)


bash = '''
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#set -x

INTERVAL="1"  # update interval in seconds

n='''+n+'''

# How many time script will work.
start=1
end=2 # put the number for minues. 3600 is 1 hour.
#end=$(( 1 * 2700 ))

while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
    #echo "$start"
    ((start = start + 1))

    # Capture packets.
    R1=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/rx_bytes`
    T1=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/tx_bytes`
    sleep $INTERVAL
    R2=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/rx_bytes`
    T2=`cat /sys/class/net/$n/statistics/tx_bytes`
    TBPS=`expr $T2 - $T1`
    RBPS=`expr $R2 - $R1`
    TKBPS=`expr $TBPS / 1024`
    RKBPS=`expr $RBPS / 1024`
    echo "TX $1: $TKBPS kB/s RX $1: $RKBPS kB/s"

    # Sum number of packets sent and received on an interface
    SUM=$(expr $RKBPS)

    # If there is internet traffic, reset count to zero.
    if (( $SUM >= 10 ));then
        ((i = 0))
        echo "Connection is active:"
    fi

    now=$(( $SUM ))
    max=$((sum>max?sum:max))
    if [ $now -gt $max ] ; then
        max=$now
    fi

    wget -q --spider http://example.com
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "Online"
        ((no_internet = 0 ))
    else
#       echo "Offline"
        no_internet=$(( no_internet+1 ))
    fi

    if [ $no_internet -gt 10 ] ; then
        echo "off"
        /sbin/shutdown -h now
    fi


echo "The SUM is: $SUM"
echo "The maximum download bandwidth is: $max"
#echo
echo $start "Seconds" 'of' $end "Seconds until end"

done
# When script reach here then will shutdown the system.
/sbin/shutdown -h now

'''
capture()

#-----HERE I WANT TO PUT 2 VARIABLES

#start variable
start= #----result from bash shell script above

#end variable 
end= #----result from bash shell script above
```

Comment: If you do `os.environ['end'] = '1800'` before you call `subprocess.run`, the bash shell will inherit that variable.

Comment: I'm trying to understand your question, but am not sure. You have a Python script that starts some bash scripts, correct? And you want the bash scripts to pass a value back to the Python script? Just once at the end? Or repeatedly? Or something else?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not native speaker so It is difficult to explain. So I want start and end variable to pass below to the python app. I missed to write in my question that I want to pass start variable with end variable at the end of the script. Yes repeatedly, because when start variable changes....Do you want to correct my question then ulpload all app program?

Comment: @TimRoberts I am sorry I missed to write in my question that I need the start variable too from bash shell part. So I want to pass variable in python part at the end of app note the beginning as you said.

Comment: The variable comes in to you as `os.environ['end']`.  You can modify it before calling another process.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I want to pass start variable too. I don't want to put manually. start variable changes please look at my question. start variable count seconds. I want every time change start variable inside bash shell part of script then below the same app pass start variable in python part of the same file. I hope to understand me.

Comment: Surely, since I have shown you how to fetch one variable, you can figure out how to fetch a different variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import subprocess


def get_n() -> str:
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        n = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        n = input('Please input `n`: ')
    return n


## ----STARTING BASH SHELL----

BASH = '''
#!/usr/bin/env bash


INTERVAL="1"  # update interval in seconds

n={}

# How many time script will work.
start=1
end=1800 # put the number for minues. 3600 is 1 hour.


while [[ $start -le $end ]]
do
.....
.....
.....
 echo $start "Seconds" 'of' $end "Seconds until end"

'''
## ----END OF BASH SHELL

def capture(n, bash=BASH) -> str:
    return subprocess.run(bash.format(repr(n)), shell=True, check=True, capture_output=True).stdout.strip().decode()

def main():
    ret = capture(get_n())
    print('Output of bash result:\n'+ret)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for answering but it doesn't work. I tried and change this line `def capture(n, bash=BASH)` with bash not capital as you wrote.  I also missed to write that I need start variable to pass on the python part.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

Here's a bash script called `script.sh` that accepts 2 parameters and outputs each parameter doubled:

```
#!/bin/bash
p1=$1
p2=$2
((result1=p1*2))
((result2=p2*2))
echo "${result1} ${result2}"
```

Now call it from Python and get the results:

```
import subprocess 
sp = subprocess.run(["./script.sh","1","5"], capture_output=True)
result1, result2 = sp.stdout.split()
print(result1, result2)   # prints 2, 10
```

**Original Answer**

If you want to pass values **into** a script that you execute, you have the following options:

- Command-line parameters
- environment variables
- `stdin`
- file or some other method

Let's look at each in turn...

### Command-line parameters

You call your script with command-line parameters like this:

```
./SomeScript a "another param"
```

or, if the caller is Python:

```
sp = subprocess.run(["./SomeScript", "a", "another param"])
```

Then, inside the called script, you access the parameters like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
param1="$1"
param2="$2"
echo "First param: $param1, second param: $param2"
```

Or, if the called script is Python:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1:])
```

### Environment variables

You set an environment variable before starting the script, using either of these methods:

```
export name="Simon"
./SomeScript
```

or:

```
name="Simon" ./SomeScript
```

or, if the caller is Python:

```
import os
os.environ['name'] = 'Simon'
```

Then, inside the script, you can access `$name`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "name is $name"
```

or, if the called script is Python:

```
import os
print(os.environ['name'])
```

### via `stdin`

You send some value to the script on its `stdin` using one of these methods:

```
printf "Simon" | ./SomeScript
```

or, using a `bash` *"here-string"*:

```
./SomeScript <<< "Simon"
```

Then, inside your script, you read the value from `stdin` into a variable with:

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r name
```

Or, if the called script is Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
v = input()
print(f'Read from stdin: {v}')
```

*Note that you could equally read from `sys.stdin` or other methods.*

### via file or some other method

Other ways of passing values into scripts include letting them read from a disk file, or a database, or **Redis**, or a socket, or a message queue...

Here's an example with **Redis** which lets you share strings, atomic integers, hashes, lists, queues, images, sets and other data structures between different processes - even in different machines. First, one script puts a value into **Redis**:

```
redis-cli set name "Simon"
```

then any other process (whether `bash`, `Python`, `PHP`, `Rust`) on any machine, can retrieve the value with:

```
redis-cli get name
```

---

If you want to access the **output** from a script you called, you have the following options:

- printed result
- exit status
- text file, or database, or other app

Let's look at each in turn.

### printed result

The script prints something on its `stdout`, or `stderr` like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "Some result"
>&2 printf "Some error"
```

And the caller, if `bash` can pick it up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$( ./SomeScript )
```

Or, if the caller is Python, it can catch the output from `subprocess.run()`.

```
sp = subprocess.run(["./SomeScript"], capture_output=True)
print(sp.stdout, sp.stderr)
```

### exit status - mostly just for true/false outputs

The script exits with an exit status like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 3
```

And the caller, if `bash` can pick it up like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
./SomeScript
status=$?
```

Or, if the caller is Python, it can catch the exit status from `subprocess.run()`.

```
sp = subprocess.run(["./SomeScript"], capture_output=True)
print(sp.returncode)
```

### file output

As before, the called script can write to a file on disk, or a database, or a socket, or a message queue, or **Redis** as above.

Comment: Thank you for so many examples but I didn't understand how to do in my app. Would you like to give me an example to pass start and end variable at the end of my app?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't really understand your question. **What** do you want to pass to **what**? Do you have a Python program that starts a bash program? Does the Python program need to pass something to the bash program?

Comment: I am sorry. I have one python file that runs bash commands. I run `python3 app.py enp35s0` Look at my python code. The python app run bash commands that get network bandwidth from internet. All code are one file...bash part start after a few line from beginning. Please look at my file. so bash shell part of file have 2 variables start and end. How to pass both variable at the end of the file ? I want to pass bass shell variables (start and end)  to python part at the end of file. Do you understand me?

Comment: No, sorry. 1) You have a Python script that starts a bash script, correct? 2) The bash script calculates something, correct? 3) You want the Python script to get the values calculated by the bash script, correct?

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it still doesn't help you, please answer all my previous questions in the style 1) yes, 2) yes, 3) no, but...

Comment: 1) python script start bash scipt in the same file. I uploaded all python app Please look at again  2) As I said I have one python app file count.py. bash script part of the same file count.py calculate internet traffic . If no internet traffic script shutdown the raspberry. 3) Yes. start . I don't understand your examples. Please would you like to make an example with my 2 variables?

Comment: The example at the start of my answer does exactly that. A **Python** script calls a **bash** script with 2 parameters. The **bash** script doubles them both and the **Python** script gets the modified values.

Comment: Mark No, I am sorry. The first example is not that I want. Your example pass variable from parameter that typed from user . I want the pass variable from result from bash shell script.

Comment: No. If you read my **bash** script, you can see it calculates `result1` and `result2` itself. You can calculate anything you like. Your **bash** script can do `result=$RANDOM` and `echo $result`

Comment: I already have in bash `((start = start + 1))` then I put at the end those commands `sp = subprocess.run(["./bash"], capture_output=True)
start = sp.stdout.split()

print(start)` It doesn't work. Do you want add changes on my original question??

Comment: Why are you making things so difficult? Make a simple `bash` script that prints 42. Call it not from Python, but from your Terminal. Check it prints 42. Then call it from Python with `sp.subprocess.run(...)` and then `print(sp.stdout)`

Comment: I am not genius. I am stupid. Are these enough? I asked help here because I don't know enough python. I am not understand. I am sorry , maybe I am stupid. I post all code. Would you like to post the solution? If not I have to post a new question because I didn't solve my problem.